# Problemas com a atribuição de valores de um vetor para outro, usando malloc

Tags: c, array, malloc

Estou tentando fazer um programa que lê uma determinada quantidade de valores e o insere em um vetor que usa alocação de memória. Depois disso eu criei mais dois vetores (da mesma forma do anterior) para inserir neles o números pares e os impares. A primeira parte está funcionando corretamente, os valores estão sendo inseridos no vetor, porém, quando tento atribuir os valores pares e impares para seus respectivos arrays o programa não funciona corretamente e acaba deixando a saída confusa. O código inteiro se encontra abaixo. Desde já agradeço a ajuda.

A imagem abaixo mostra a entrada de dados e a saída.

Obs: executei o código no Replit

[image: Essa é a saída do programa]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    int *pares, *impares, qtdPares = 0, qtdImpares = 0;
    int *vetorPrincipal, tamanho = 5;
    int i;

    vetorPrincipal = (int *) malloc(tamanho*sizeof(int));

    //ler os valores do vetor
    for (i = 0; i < tamanho; i++) {
        printf("Valor %d: ", i+1);
        scanf("%d", &vetorPrincipal[i]);

        if (vetorPrincipal[i] % 2 == 0) {
            qtdPares++;
        } else {
            qtdImpares++;
        }
    }

    //alocando dinamicamente a memória para os pares e impares
    pares = (int *) malloc(qtdPares*sizeof(int));
    impares = (int *) malloc(qtdImpares*sizeof(int));

    //inserindo os valores pares e impares em seus vetores
    for (i = 0; i < qtdPares; i++) {
        if (vetorPrincipal[i] % 2 == 0) {
            pares[i] = vetorPrincipal[i];
        }
        else {
            impares[i] = vetorPrincipal[i];
        }
    } 

    //imprimir o vetor principal
    printf("\nVetor = [ ");
    for (i = 0; i < tamanho; i++) {
        printf("%d ", vetorPrincipal[i]);
    }
    printf("]");

    //imprimir pares e impares
    printf("\n\nNúmeros PARES = [ ");
    for (i = 0; i < qtdPares; i++) {
      printf("%d ", pares[i]);
    }
    printf("]");

    printf("\nNúmeros IMPARES = [ ");
    for (i = 0; i < qtdImpares; i++) {
      printf("%d ", impares[i]);
    }
    printf("]");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## **Erro do programa**

O erro do seu programa está nessa parte:

```
//inserindo os valores pares e impares em seus vetores
for (i = 0; i < qtdPares; i++) {
    if (vetorPrincipal[i] % 2 == 0) {
        pares[i] = vetorPrincipal[i];
    }
    else {
        impares[i] = vetorPrincipal[i];
    }
}
```

Aqui temos dois erros, o primeiro é fazer `i < qtdPares` ao invés de `i < tamanho`, o segundo é usar o mesmo `i` para acessar três vetores diferentes.

### **Erro lógico na condição de parada do `for`**

No seu `for` você quer percorrer todos os indices do seu `vetorPrincipal`, se ele tem `3` posições então o `for` precisa repetir `3` vezes, se tem `4` então o `for` precisa repetir `4` vezes e assim por diante. No seu exemplo você usa a variável `tamanho` para armazenar o tamanho do vetor e é ela quem você deve usar no seu `loop`, desta forma:

```
for (i = 0; i < tamanho; i++) { // Igual quando voce leu os valores para o vetor
```

### **Erro ao usar o mesmo `i` para acessar três vetores diferentes**

Após alterar a condição de parada do seu `for` nós teremos o seguinte código:

```
for (i = 0; i < tamanho; i++) {
    if (vetorPrincipal[i] % 2 == 0) {
        pares[i] = vetorPrincipal[i];
    }
    else {
        impares[i] = vetorPrincipal[i];
    }
}
```

Considerando que o `vetorPrincipal` tenha os seguintes valores:

> 1 2 3 4 5

Aqui o problema é utilizar o mesmo `i` para todos os vetores. O erro é que você está colocando os números `ímpares` e `pares` na mesma posição do `vetorPrincipal` e isso é um erro.

Vamos considerar `i = 3`.

> Se i == 3, logo vetorPrincipal[3] == 4

> Quatro é par então vamos colocar em pares[i]

> Subistituindo i por seu valor (3), temos pares[3]

E aqui temos o problema, a posição `pares[3]` não faz parte do seu vetor (Seu array tem tamanho 2, pois só tem dois pares). Quando você imprimir `pares` o número quatro não vai aparecer, pois ele foi colocado em uma posição desconhecida da memória.

Seu programa produz as seguintes saídas:

> pares: 0 2

> impares: 1 0 0

Observe que o número dois está na posicao `pares[1]` (segunda posição do vetor), pois quando o conteúdo `vetorPrincipal` era `2`, o `i` era `1`. Veja:

> i == 0, 1 // Adiciona 1 na posicao 0 do vetor impar

> i == 1, 2 // Adiciona 2 na posicao 1 do vetor par

> i == 2, 3 // Adiciona 3 na posicao 2 do vetor impar

> i == 3, 4 // Adiciona 4 na posicao 3 do vetor par, essa posicao nao faz parte do vetor

> i == 4, 5 // Adiciona 5 na posicao 4 do vetor impar, essa posicao nao faz parte do vetor

## **Solução**

Para resolver esse problema você precisa ter uma variável para cada `vetor`, desta forma:

```
// Voce pode declarar as variaveis dentro do for se quiser
// for (int i = 0, i_par = 0, i_impar = 0; i < tamanho; i++)
int i_par = 0;
int i_impar = 0;

for (i = 0; i < tamanho; i++) {
    if (vetorPrincipal[i] % 2 == 0) {
        pares[i_par] = vetorPrincipal[i];
        i_par++;
    }
    else {
        impares[i_impar] = vetorPrincipal[i];
        i_impar++;
    }
}
```

Repare que agora os valores serão colocados nas posições corretas

Veja seu código funcionando [aqui](https://ideone.com/Wy4zxm).